# ImportError: cannot import name 'Session' from 'tensorflow'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm struggle with running module.

```
from tensorflow import Session, ConfigProto, GPUOptions
gpuoptions = GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
session = Session(config=ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpuoptions))
K.set_session(session)
classifier = Sequential()
```

I don't know why it's not working.

It just shows me:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Session' from 'tensorflow' (C:\Users\hayou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py)
```

Comment: Which tensorflow version are you using? Tensorflow v2 does not have Session anymore. Check with `import tensorflow; print(tensorflow.__version__)`

Comment: Thank you. after i installed tensorflow 1.15.0 version, it works well :) @mrzo

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're using TensorFlow 2.x. In that case, use tf.compat.v1.--function--() instead.

```
import tensorflow as tf
gpuoptions = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
session = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpuoptions))
K.set_session(session)
classifier = Sequential()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using tensorflow `v2.2` which doesn't have *Session*. However it has been present in previous versions, so you might want to install an older version of tensorflow like `v1.15` which contains *Session* class.
`pip install tensorflow==1.15`
I'm not exactly sure this is the best solution, but it worked for me, so I hope it does work for you as well!